# How to display acronyms by order of appearance in the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In the code below, I want the acronyms to be displayed  **by order of appearance** in the body in the list of acronyms and the glossaries **in alphabetic order** at the end of the book. When I use the option `sort=use`, the two Lists are displayed by order of appearance in the document body. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{maths}{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is foo bar}}

\newglossaryentry{chem}{
    name=chem,
    description={Chemistry is foo bar}}    

\newacronym{dm}{DM}{diagonal matrix}    
\newacronym{aca}{ACA}{a contrived acronym}    
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\chapter{Foo}
I'm talking about \gls{maths}, \gls{chem}, \acrshort{dm}, and \acrshort{aca}.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [Sorting Options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sortingoptions) section of the manual, the only way to apply different sorting methods for the glossaries is to use the `sort` key in `\printnoidxglossary`, which means using the [Option 1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) approach.